# Deciphering nginx error log entry

Tags: nginx, logging

In a Django app I maintain, nginx acts as a reverse proxy with gunicorn as the application server. My nginx error logs are filled with error messages such as these:

```
*12498147 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 86.123.57.195, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP
```

Can someone explain in layman's terms what precisely this means? Moreover, does it have anything to do with the following entries in my `nginx.conf` file?

```
client_body_timeout 1m;
client_header_timeout 1m;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that gunicorn did not return data within the timeout nginx expects. Look at your gunicorn logs from the same time stamp for more information on what was happening.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. In gunicorn logs, I'm seeing `[2017-04-22 08:14:42 +0000] [1259] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:1359)`. This happened due to a DDOS attack. My workers went offline it seems.